# Linux (Ubuntu) - how to evaluate exit code of command after its output has been piped?

Tags: shell

In normal command I can execute other commands based on exit code:

```
command.sh && command_if_OK.sh || command_if_fail.sh
```

But I would like to pipe output to log file AND then execute commands according to exit code. Something like this, but obviously it will not work, because the exit code will be one of tee, not original command. How to do it?

```
command.sh | tee -a logfile.txt && execute_if_command_ok.sh || execute_if_command_failed.sh
```

any advice please?

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692000/how-do-i-write-stderr-to-a-file-while-using-tee-with-a-pipe) to learn about pipelines and STDERR and STDOUT redirection.

Comment: Thanks. The article at link is very complicated, but I think it does not answer the question. I want to display output in terminal and add it to log file and I know how to do that. In addition, I want to execute one command when original command is successful and I want to execute second command if there is exit code (not exit code of tee, but of the original command). I did not find that answered.

Comment: Crossdupe https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-status-of-process-thats-piped-to-another . Also in some shells instead of piping you can use process substitution: `blah >(tee -a save) && good || bad`. Remember that with `x && y || z` y is done if x succeeds, but z is done if x fails _or_ y fails; make sure you want that.

Comment: Dave I have some problem with your elegant solution. I tried ```curl "some_url" >(tee -a tglog.txt) && echo Success || echo Fail``` and even when ```curl``` completes successfully, it returns error ```curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL``` and then command always evaluates as failed.

Answer (score 0):

Going back to properly explain [my link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692000/how-do-i-write-stderr-to-a-file-while-using-tee-with-a-pipe). Ripping a piece of code off of the answer to build off of, see this `sh` file (lhunath):

```
out="${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/out.$$" err="${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/err.$$"
mkfifo "$out" "$err"
trap 'rm "$out" "$err"' EXIT
tee -a stdout.log < "$out" &
tee -a stderr.log < "$err" >&2 &
[sh file here] >"$out" 2>"$err"
```

So the link walks you through all this but the files `stdout.log` and `stderr.log` include the output of `command`. You can then `grep` stderr.log to check for errors, and if there are you can then act upon them. You can add the following to the code:

```
if grep "" stderr.log; then
    command_if_fail
else
    command_if_OK
fi
```

What this does is it checks the error log for any occurrences of errors, and if it finds one then it executes the fail command, and the OK command otherwise.

**UPDATE** see dave_thompson_085's comment for a cleaner solution